# "Колбасный куттер". Неграмотность или особенность языка?

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология, недопустимая-метка, заимствования

Посмотрев сюжет о колбасном заводе, поспорил о "колбасном куттере".
Оппонент считает, что правильно говорить *каттер* (от анг. *cut*), что — цитирую — "иностранные слова довольно часто звучат в русском языке не по-своему, а просто неграмотно ...", и т.д.
Мне за язык родной обидно. Кто прав?

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке — куттер, и это закреплено в словарях. Многие заимствованные слова у нас звучат совсем не так, как их иноязычные "предки". Ничего с этим не поделаешь. И это нормально. Любой язык, заимствуя "чужие" слова, переделывает их на свой лад. Так, например, русский *соболь* превратился в английский *sable* (сэйбл).

> Куттер колбасный (от англ. cut — резать) — машина для тонкого или структурного измельчения мяса и приготовления фарша при производстве полукопчёных, варёно-копченых, варёных, сырокопчёных, ливерных колбас, сарделек, сосисок, паштетов из рыбы, птицы и мяса. ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9))
>
> куттер, -а ([Орфографический словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80&all=x))